# Is true the following assertion?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

$\forall f\in C^\infty(\Bbb R):\quad \int^\infty_0 \big(16t^2|f''(t)|^2+t^2|f(t)|^2-8t^2|f'(t)|^2\big)dt>0$

any counter-example will be appreciate.

Comment: Please share context. Where is this from? How did you come up with this specific formula, what are your thoughts what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true. Take $f(t) = \exp(t)$ as a smooth counterexample.

We have:

- $f(t) = \exp(t) \in C^{\infty}$
- $\exp(t) > 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$
- $f(t) = f'(t) = f''(t) = \exp(t)$

So your integral

$$
I_1 = \int^\infty_0 t^2|f''(t)|^2+t^2|f(t)|^2-8t^2|f'(t)|^2 dt
$$

can for $f(t) = \exp(t)$ be simplified to

$$
\begin{align}
I_1 &= \int^\infty_0 t^2 \exp(t)^2 + t^2 \exp(t)^2 - 8 t^2 \exp(t)^2 dt \\
&= -6 \int^\infty_0 t^2 \exp(t)^2 dt \rightarrow -\infty
\end{align}
$$

so $I_1$ approaches negative infinity.

**Edit**: Considering your updated question, you have

$$
I_2 = \int^\infty_0 16 t^2|f''(t)|^2+t^2|f(t)|^2-8t^2|f'(t)|^2 dt
$$

and exclude the zero function explicitly. As stated in a comment, $I_2 = 0$ for $f(t) = \exp(t/2)$. However, I don't think that even the relaxed inequality $I_2 \geq 0$ is true. Consider

$$
f(t) = (t + 1)^{-0.4 t}
$$

With this $f$, the exact value of the integral is very hard to calculate, but using a numeric solver, the value is

$$
I_2 \approx -0.1668
$$

Alternatively, for a function that is defined on all $\mathbb{R}$, take

$$
f(t) = (t^2/10 + 1)^{-0.4 t}
$$

for which you get $I_2 \approx -0.1588$. Of course, by scaling $f$ with a constant, you can make the integral even "more negative".

I doubt that the statement is true, even with your new assumptions.

Comment: Thanks, I m sorry  I forgot the term16 in the first member (Please see above)

Comment: @RyoKen First: Are you sure about the inequality being strict? Because then the zero function $f(t) = 0$ is a trivial counterexample, as for that $f$ we have $I = 0$. Maybe you mean $I \geq 0$?

Comment: @SampleTime.I suppose moreover that $f\not=0$

Comment: @RyoKen That doesn't solve the problem. Take $f(t) = \exp(t/2)$, you still get $I = 0$.

Comment: Thanks.  I think we can say $\forall f\in C^\infty(\Bbb R):\quad \int^\infty_0 \big(16t^2|f''(t)|^2+t^2|f(t)|^2-8t^2|f'(t)|^2\big)dt\geq0$

Comment: @RyoKen I don't think so. I updated my answer with a new counterexample that is negative.

Comment: With $f(t)=\exp(-1/10 t)$ we get $ \int^\infty_0 \big(16t^2|f''(t)|^2+t^2|f(t)|^2-8t^2|f'(t)|^2\big)dt<0$.

Comment: @RyoKen Not really. With $f(t) = \exp(-t/10)$ you get $I = 1152/5 > 0$.

Comment: @SamplTime, You are right.

Comment: Even Maple can not calculate both examples given before. Can I find a sequence. Can I find a sequence  $(f_n)\in L^2(\Bbb R)\  \lim_{n\to\infty } \int^\infty_0 \big(16t^2|f''_n(t)|^2+t^2|f_n(t)|^2-8t^2|f'_n(t)|^2\big)dt=-4$  and $||f_n||_2=1$. Thanks a lot

Comment: @RyoKen Well, that is a new question, so I would recommend that you open a new thread for this.